# Next rotation number at which, slot machine reels do not show a particular symbol

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Assume a slot machine has 3 reels.

The left reel has 7 pictures of the following numbers:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

The middle reel has 5 pictures of the following numbers:

```
        3  
        4  
        5  
        6  
        7
```

The right reel has 3 pictures of the following numbers:

```
                   5  
                   6  
                   7
```

In each second all reels rotate only once in the same direction and the slot machine is following a sequence like below:

**Slot Machine Symbol | Rotation No**

```
       1 3 5         1
       2 4 6         2
       3 5 7         3
       4 6 5         4
       5 7 6         5
       6 3 7         6
       7 4 5         7
       1 5 6         8
       2 6 7         9
       . . .         . 
       . . .         . 
       . . .         . 
       . . .         . 
       4 4 7         102
       5 5 5         103
       6 6 6         104
       7 7 7         105
```

We can see the slot machine sequence starts with 1 3 5 and ends with 7 7 7 and there are 3.5.7=105 permutations.

My question is, after Rotation Number 6, what is the **next Rotation Number** at which **symbol/picture 3** is missing from all the three reels (left, middle, right)?

After Rotation Number 6,I don't want to go through the reel sequences one by one. I want to solve it through equation or by intelligent process/method so that, later I can use the same method for larger number of reels and symbols.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a modular arithmetic problem.

In general, suppose the three reels have $a, b$ and $c$ number of symbols on them, and we see our symbol of interest $x$ only at position $p_a, p_b,$ and $p_c$ respectively. Then on rotation $R$ we see $x$ if $R\equiv p_a \bmod a$ or $R\equiv p_b \bmod b$ or $R\equiv p_c \bmod c$. And the next appearance can be found by taking the minimum of  $1 + (p_a- (R+1) \bmod a)$, $1 + (p_b- (R+1) \bmod b)$ and $1 + (p_c- (R+1) \bmod c)$, where "$\bmod$" is here finding least non-negative residues.